# How to use SQL Case in Group by Clause?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Case in my select and in group by clause and I'm working in JAVA. Whenever I execute my java program it says:

> Column 'dbo.JOHN_Dashboard.Log_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My Query is:

```
SELECT EP.Site_Code AS [Site_Code], DB.[Site] AS [Site], DB.[Utility] AS [Utility], 
        CASE ? WHEN 'Raw' THEN dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,DB.[log_date]),0) 
        WHEN 'Hour'  THEN dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Day'   THEN dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Week'  THEN dateadd(wk,datediff(wk,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Month' THEN dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Year'  THEN dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,DB.[log_date]),0)                                                     
        ELSE DB.[log_date]
        END AS [log_date],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DB.[value] >= 0 THEN DB.[value] ELSE 0 END) AS [value],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DB.[Cost] >=0 THEN DB.[cost] ELSE 0 END) AS [Cost],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DB.[CO2] >=0 THEN DB.[CO2] ELSE 0 END) AS [CO],
        MT.[Meter_type_name] AS [Meter Type],
        MN.[Meter_Name] AS [Meter Name],
        U.[Unit_Name] AS [Units],
        EP.EnergyPoint_ID AS [Meter_ID],
        EP.Parent_ID AS [Parent],
        EP.Meter_Description AS [Meter_Description] 
FROM [dbo].[JOHN_Dashboard] DB
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EnergyPoints] EP ON DB.[EnergyPoint_ID] = EP.[EnergyPoint_ID] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Meter_Types] MT ON MT.[Meter_Type_ID] = EP.[Meter_Type_ID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Meter_Names] MN ON MN.[Meter_Name_ID] = EP.[Meter_Name_ID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Units] U ON U.[Unit_ID] = EP.[Unit_id]
WHERE [log_date] >= ? AND [Log_Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, ?)
AND ( ? IS NULL OR EP.Energypoint_ID = ?)
GROUP BY EP.Site_Code, DB.[Site], DB.[Utility], MT.[Meter_type_name],           
        MN.[Meter_Name], U.[Unit_Name], EP.[EnergyPoint_ID],
        EP.[Parent_ID], EP.[Meter_Description],
        CASE ? WHEN 'Raw' THEN dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Hour'  THEN dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Day'   THEN dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Week'  THEN dateadd(wk,datediff(wk,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Month' THEN dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        WHEN 'Year'  THEN dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
        ELSE DB.[log_date] END ;
```

The parameters i'm passing are:

1. 'Week'
2. '2016-05-16'
3. '2016-05-22'
4. 6044
5. 6044
6. 'Week'

Note: This query runs without error in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: You are selecting a column which is not in the `GROUP BY` clause or is an aggregate (e.g. `SUM(some_column)`).  Fix this and the error will go away.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know the reason of the error as you mentioned as well. The thing i don't know that what i'm doing wrong in sytax.

Comment: Can you provide the query with the parameters filled in?  What does `CASE ?` become when the query fails?

Comment: @destination-data I'm setting "Week" in Case as parameter.

Comment: Is that enough parameters?  What values are you passing to this line `...AND (? IS NULL OR EP.Energypoint_ID = ?)...`.  Can you get Java to return the SQL statement it is executing?  Suspect the wrong values are ending up in the wrong places.

Comment: @destination-data Sorry forget to mention that. I have updated the question please have a look now. Thank you.

Comment: If you move the bulk of the query into a sub-select including the case statements and then do your grouping and aggregation on the sub-select results does the error go away? I try not to duplicate large case statements like that in group by and select because later on the code can drift.

Comment: @SMM, excellent advice! Derived table queries are so much easier to maintain!

Comment: @SMM Can you please post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested here is a reworked version of your code using a sub-query before grouping. Since I don't have your database I can't guarantee that I have everything exactly right but give this a try.

I recommend always using a sub-query when your group by has complicated logic that will be repeated in the select. Some people would probably drop the second criteria and just say whenever the group by has complicated logic.

```
SELECT  sub.Site_Code, sub.[Site], sub.[Utility], sub.[Meter Type],
        sub.[log_date],
        SUM(sub.[value]) as [value],
        SUM(sub.[Cost]) as [cost],
        SUM(sub.[CO]) as [CO],
        sub.[Meter Name], sub.[Units], sub.[Meter_ID],
        sub.[Parent], sub.[Meter_Description]
FROM    (
        SELECT EP.Site_Code AS [Site_Code], DB.[Site] AS [Site], DB.[Utility] AS [Utility], 
                CASE ? WHEN 'Raw' THEN dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,DB.[log_date]),0) 
                WHEN 'Hour'  THEN dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
                WHEN 'Day'   THEN dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
                WHEN 'Week'  THEN dateadd(wk,datediff(wk,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
                WHEN 'Month' THEN dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,DB.[log_date]),0)
                WHEN 'Year'  THEN dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,DB.[log_date]),0)                                                     
                ELSE DB.[log_date]
                END AS [log_date],
                CASE WHEN DB.[value] >= 0 THEN DB.[value] ELSE 0 END AS [value],
                CASE WHEN DB.[Cost] >=0 THEN DB.[cost] ELSE 0 END AS [Cost],
                CASE WHEN DB.[CO2] >=0 THEN DB.[CO2] ELSE 0 END AS [CO],
                MT.[Meter_type_name] AS [Meter Type],
                MN.[Meter_Name] AS [Meter Name],
                U.[Unit_Name] AS [Units],
                EP.EnergyPoint_ID AS [Meter_ID],
                EP.Parent_ID AS [Parent],
                EP.Meter_Description AS [Meter_Description] 
        FROM [dbo].[JOHN_Dashboard] DB
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[EnergyPoints] EP ON DB.[EnergyPoint_ID] = EP.[EnergyPoint_ID] 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Meter_Types] MT ON MT.[Meter_Type_ID] = EP.[Meter_Type_ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Meter_Names] MN ON MN.[Meter_Name_ID] = EP.[Meter_Name_ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Units] U ON U.[Unit_ID] = EP.[Unit_id]
        WHERE [log_date] >= ? AND [Log_Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, ?)
        AND ( ? IS NULL OR EP.Energypoint_ID = ?)
        ) sub
GROUP BY sub.Site_Code, sub.[Site], sub.[Utility], sub.[Meter Type],           
        sub.[Meter Name], sub.[Units], sub.[Meter_ID],
        sub.[Parent], sub.[Meter_Description], sub.[log_date];
```